# Django html page does not display a variable i passed in views

Tags: python, html, django, display

i am a beginner with Django and i encountered a problem. I wrote a code which allows me to add different products and categories from admin, and then display them on a html page. However, when i click on any of the displayed products i want my product description to be displayed in another html page. The first page is working just fine( product_list.html), however i am having trouble with the second one (product_detail.html).

**urls.py** ( without the imports):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^category/(?P<categoryid>\d+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    #url(r'^list/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    re_path('^$', views.product_list, name = 'product_list'),
    url(r'^list/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

***views.py***

```
def product_list(request, categoryid = 1): *this one is working*

    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products =  Product.objects.all().filter(category_id=categoryid)
    context = {'categories': categories,
               'products': products
               }
    return render(request, 'shop/product_list.html', context)

def product_detail(request, id=1): *this one is not displaying anything*
    productt = Product.objects.all().filter(id = id)
    return render(request, 'shop/product_detail.html', {'product': productt})
```

**product_detail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
       <a href="http://localhost:8000/shop/list/{{product.id}}/">{{product.description}}</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea why the page rendered by product_detail does not display anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DanielRoseman is right, but to prevent an error in case there's no Product with that id, you have 3 options. The first one is to do a queryset and get the first element, then check if there is a result, like this:

```
productt = Product.objects.filter(id=id).first()
if productt is None:
    # do something to let the user know the product doesn't exist
```

The second option is to wrap your `get` method arround a `try except`:

```
try:
    productt = Product.objects.get(id=id)
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    # do something to let the user know the product doesn't exist
```

The final option is to use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), which:

> Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

productt = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
```

Comment: Hi . Thank you, but i have a question. The other html displays exatcly what i need and i used the same sintax, without .get . Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because in the `product_list` view your are passing a list of `Product`s, so you're probably using a `{% for product in products %}` to iterate through every item, meanwhile in the `product_detail` view you're suppose to pass an instance `Product`, not a list. Let me know if this clears up for you

Comment: Ohh. Well yes, i thought that since there s only one product with a specific id, then it will pass a list made of only one instance. I did not know that it being a list would be a problem.

Comment: When you use `filter` it will **always** return a `QuerySet`, no matter what field you're using. So now that you know, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

`filter` returns a queryset. Querysets don't have `id` or `description` attributes.

You need to use `get` to get an instance:

```
productt = Product.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: Hi . Thank you, but i have a question. The other html displays exatcly what i need and i used the same sintax, without .get . Do you have any idea why?