# Django: Extracting the value from a Queryset and store in a variable for filtering later on

Tags: python, django, filter, parameter-passing, extract

I would like to extract a value from a queryset and then store it in a variable so that I can use it as a filter criterion later on. How may I do this?

This userprofile model is linked to the User model hence the User.id would be the same as the user_id in userprofile model:

```
class userprofile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, ...)
    age=....
    user_race=models.Charfield(.....)
```

I want to get the race of this user and store it as a variable "x", so when I query the following way:

```
x = userprofile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).user_race
#doesn't seem to get the race of this user...how to get it?
```

Question: is "x" now a string variable or still a queryset in the form of a list of dictionary?

Then I want to use "x" as the criterion when filtering for another queryset using the following model:

```
class cuisines(models.Model):
    portion=....
    race=models.Charfield(.....)
```

Query:

```
y = cuisines.objects.filter(race='x')       #This is to get all the results as long as the race of the user matches the race value in the cuisines model.
```

Please help me in better understanding where I have gone wrong in this logic/process.

thank you.

Comment: Use `get` not `filter`. (Actually, if you had run this code, you would have got an AttributeError; `x` wouldn't exist at all.)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995147/8895630) can help you out.

Comment: @ DanielRoseman: if `x` doesn't exist, then surely the `y = cuisine.objects.filter(race=x)` will not work either. How then can I access the value of the user's race via the userprofile? And then use it later on to filter the Cuisine Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your query like this:-

```
user_profile = userprofile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
x = user_profile.user_race
```

Then, the next query should be like this:-

```
y = cuisines.objects.filter(race=x)
```

Comment: yes, thank you. I tried something like that but it didn't work initially. After inspecting my userprofile Model (userprofile.user_race) values again, I realised there is a `\r` included in the string i.e. 'japanese\r'. This entire string would therefore be stored in the `x` variable, which is of course not the same as the value in the Cuisines.race (which is 'japanese').

Comment: Rather use `user_id` instead of `user__id` to avoid an unnecessary join.